# Docker not copying local .ssh folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have these 2 commands in my Dockerfile

```
COPY .ssh/ /bin
COPY stockfish/ /bin/stockfish
```

When I check the container, the second folder is there but not the .ssh. I can't figure out why it's not being copied.

I don't have a dockerignore. Also the .ssh is a local folder, not the ~/.ssh.

I've tried chmod 777 if it was maybe a permissions thing but no.

Comment: _"I don't have a dockerignore"_... do you have a `.dockerignore`?

Comment: I do not, I have a gitignore though

Comment: From the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) => `If <src> is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata. Note: The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.`. So with your example command (`COPY .ssh/ /bin`) your files contained in `.ssh` should actually be present at the root of `/bin` in the container. If you want a `.ssh` folder inside `/bin` in the image => `COPY .ssh /bin/.ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to inspect the docker image!
Once inside the container, navigate to /bin/ and check if the .ssh/ folder is there.

```
docker run -it your_image_name /bin/sh
```

Comment: .ssh is not there.

Comment: In certain situations, problems may arise due to issues with the build cache. Consider executing the build using the --no-cache option to initiate a fresh build.


docker build --no-cache -t your_image_name .